# Loading data from a CSV file to a lineWithFocusChart in D3

Tags: csv, d3.js, nvd3.js

i'm trying to load data from a CSV file and present it to a D3 chart using the lineWithFocusChart model. I'm new to D3 charts but was able to understand how the basics work and went through the examples.

Here is my code:

```js
nv.addGraph(function() {
  var chart = nv.models.lineWithFocusChart();
chart.xAxis.tickFormat(d3.format(',f'));
chart.x2Axis.tickFormat(d3.format(',f'));
chart.yAxis.tickFormat(d3.format(',.2f'));
chart.y2Axis.tickFormat(d3.format(',.2f'));
  d3.select('#chart svg').datum(testData()).call(chart);
  nv.utils.windowResize(chart.update);
  return chart;
});


function loadData()
{
  d3.csv("/data/datademo.csv", function(error, data) {
    if (error) {
      console.log("ERROR: " + error)
    } else {
      console.log("loadData: " + data);
      return data;
    }
  });
}


function testData() {
  var datasensors = loadData().map(function(data, i) {
    return {
      key: 'Sensor ' + i,
      values: data
    };
  });
  return datasensors;;
}
```

```html
<div id="chart">
  <svg></svg>
</div>
```

The data in my CSV is as simple as it gets (it's suppose to load ECG data):

```
x,y
0,-69.743590
1,0.195360
2,0.195360
3,-1.758242
```

I'm getting the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined
```

and the chart doesn't even loads.

Can anyone help me with this.

Comment: Even using the hardcoded values I get a D3 error for every value (`Invalid value for <path> attribute transform="translate(NaN,NaN)`"
`
    var datasensors = [            {
                 key: "Sensor 1",
                 values: [[0.000000,-69.743590], [0.003906,0.195360], [0.007812,0.195360]]
                },
                {
                 key: "Sensor 2",
                 values: [[0.000000,108.034188],[0.003906,0.195360],[0.007812,0.586081]]
                }
            ];
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The loadData().map(.....) should be in the callback function of  d3.csv("/data/datademo.csv".......).

You are now trying to use the return of the loadData() function, but the data are not yet loaded, that's why you become 'undefined'.

I hope it helps.

Comment: Hi @nipro, first of all, thanks for your help. I've changed the loadData function:  
`  
    function loadData()  
        {
            d3.csv("/data/datademo.csv", function(data) {  
     ECGDataSensors = data.map(function(d) { return [ +d["x"], +d["y"] ]; });  
        });  
    }  
`   
and try to create the chart directly with:    
`
    d3.select('#chart svg').datum(ECGDataSensors).call(chart);
`    
and got the message: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined in nv.d3.js line 5887... I can't figure out why!

Comment: Try putting the `d3.select('#chart svg').datum(ECGDataSensors).call(chart);` inside the callback. 

Something like:
`function loadData() { 
    d3.csv("/data/datademo.csv", function(data) { 
     ECGDataSensors = data.map(function(d) { return [ +d["x"], +d["y"] ]; }); 
     d3.select('#chart svg').datum(ECGDataSensors).call(chart);
    }); 
   } `

If this doesn't work, could you prepare a JSFiddle with your full code? I could have a look at it.

Comment: Hi @nipro. Thanks for your help. I've managed to load the CSV data inside the callback. I'm now having other problems (viewport won't work with a small selection - higher zoom), but if i'm not able to fix it, I'll probably try another chart component. I'm trying to load ECG data but probably D3 isn't the best option...